# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to insert data into the table using `Storedprocedure.`

I have written code like below

```
OracleConnection ObjPriCon = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
    ObjPriCon.Open();
    string spquery = "xxcus.pn_insert_grid_agreeement";
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(spquery, ObjPriCon);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("Mkey", OracleType.Number).Value = e.Record["Mkey"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("GrdType", OracleType.VarChar).Value = e.Record["grd_type"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("firstname", OracleType.VarChar).Value = e.Record["f_name"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("lastname", OracleType.VarChar).Value = e.Record["l_name"];

    cmd.Parameters.Add("contactdet", OracleType.Number).Value = e.Record["cont_det"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pancardDet", OracleType.VarChar).Value = e.Record["pancard_det"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("trantype", OracleType.VarChar).Value = "GDS";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("createdby", OracleType.Number).Value = Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString();

    cmd.Parameters.Add("creationdate", OracleType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("lastUpdateDate", OracleType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("lastUpdatedBy", OracleType.Number).Value = Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("deleteflag", OracleType.Char).Value = "N";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ObjPriCon.Close();
```

But at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` I am getting error as

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal.

I don't understand where the error is

Also see my SP structure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XXCUS.pn_insert_grid_agreeement (
       mkey               NUMBER,  
       GrdType           VARCHAR2,
       firstname             VARCHAR2,
       lastname             VARCHAR2,
       contactdet           NUMBER,
       pancardDet        VARCHAR2,
       trantype          VARCHAR2,
       createdby         NUMBER,
       creationdate      DATE,
       lastUpdateDate   DATE,
       lastUpdatedBy    NUMBER,
       deleteflag        CHAR
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO xxcus.xxacl_pn_grid_agreement
                   (MKEY, grd_type, f_name, l_name, cont_det, pancard_det, tran_type,
                    created_by, creation_date, last_update_date,
                    last_updated_by, delete_flag
                   )
            VALUES (mkey, GrdType, firstname,lastname, contactdet,pancardDet, trantype,
                    createdby, creationdate, lastUpdateDate,
                    lastUpdatedBy, deleteflag
                   );
    END;
```

Kindly suggest what is wrong here

**UDPATE**

`Mkey` is auto incremented column.

Comment: Are you try creationdate and lastUpdateDate add without string format?

Comment: @mwisnicki: sorry didn't got you? did u mean shd I add `hh:mm:ss` also ?

Comment: Set only DateTime.Now.Date. And tell me what is precision on your number values in database?

Comment: @mwisnicki: I added like this `DateTime.Now.Date();` but getting error as **non-invocable member 'system.datetime.now' cannot be used like a method**

Comment: @mwisnicki: i get value as `17-09-2016 19:50:15` while using `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:s")`

Comment: Just set "DateTime.Now.Date; " .And Check which line of code returns this error and what the value is set

Comment: @mwisnicki: the same line at `Date` i was getting the error as **non-invocable member 'system.datetime.now' cannot be used like a method**

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("createdby", OracleType.Number).Value = Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("lastUpdatedBy", OracleType.Number).Value = Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString();
```

With:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("lastUpdatedBy", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["userid"]);
cmd.Parameters.Add("createdby", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["userid"]);
```

Comment: after changing that, I am still getting the same error.!

Comment: i resolved that error, but by putting `mkey` column as hardcode. Because my `mkey` column is auto increment column. How to use that. currently I insert it like this `string mkey = Convert.ToInt32("1").ToString();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("mkey", OracleType.Number).Value = mkey;`

Comment: but you mentioned that `mkey` is auto-increment so I guess you should not insert it at all.

Comment: Yes, but I guess I need to create a sequence in SP for using it. Can u help me with that ?